# W8.1 Crash when GPU Enabled?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, crash

I'm really confused about this one, so prepare for a long post.

I've had this same computer setup for about a year now, never had any issues.

- CPU: Intel 4870K w/ Integrated Graphics driving a 1440*900 Monitor over VGA
- Mob: Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UP5 TH
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6870 driving a 1920*1080 Monitor over HDMI

Recently, I've been having a few issues with my AMD Graphics Card.  Having done some research, trial/error, troubleshooting, etc., I'm 90% certain this is a hardware issue (GRAM specifically), however, I'd like some second opinions.

When the AMD card is plugged into a monitor on boot, the POST Screen shows, I can go into the BIOS, works fine.  As soon as Windows tries to load, nothing happens.  It doesn't even start the loading screen.

When both monitors are plugged into the integrated chip, the entire system loads fine, with no errors, crashes, anything.

When I start the machine with only the 1440*900 monitor plugged into the integrated chip, and the 1080p monitor not plugged into anything, Windows loads.  If I plug the monitor in after Windows has loaded, I hear the first 2-3 notes of the "you plugged in an accessory" chime, and the computer crashes.  No blue screen, the monitors just go blank (it has to remap the displays, I get that) but the sound freezes (just holds one pitch) and it does nothing until I reset or unplug.

I have reinstalled the AMD drivers, I have done a system restore to 2 weeks ago when it was working fine, and, as I said above, I'm 90% sure this is a hardware issue.  Anybody have other opinions or things I should try?

Update:  I unplugged all my hard drives, and put in an old laptop drive I had sitting around.  The system worked fine (with both monitors in their rightful places - e.g. both 1080p into Radeon 6870 and 900p into Intel Chip) until the AMD Driver installation.  Once the driver finished installing, the computer hard locked.  And on the brand new OS, it is in the same place as the other one.

Update #2:  I've confirmed that it is the card, and not the mobo/PSU.  My roommate had an old GTX 260 sitting around (higher TDP than the 6870) and it works 100% in the computer with all the same parts, both monitors plugged into it, after driver installation.  Still would like to have opinions on what exactly causes the Hard Locks (Going off of the comments, I'm considering GPU Power hookups inside the casing, but a bad sector or two of GRAM is still a possibility)

Comment: I am getting (with my psycic abilities) the idea that it is possible that the PSU could be an issue here, whenever the real power consumption of the gpu hits you get a hard lock but not a power off. Could be issues with power (somewhere) or the motherboard or gpu item and capacitor degridations and all.  Best way to tell would be to clone the present system os partition, so you can return to it at any time you want , and install a fresh  OS, that is way less likely to have any software issues.  With that MB  you could also "lower" a few GPU things, like setting the gen and link down to test.

Comment: @Psycogeek - great idea, I would vote this up as an answer.

Comment: I need facts, You get it working and discover the actual problem and get it back to fully operational, then you could post your own answer.  anything else is speculation, hope, and ideas.

Comment: Most of the times, the only way to solve a problem is if You start at a point, keep guessing and try to get closer and closer to the root of the problem untill You make it work. You can always update your answer and/or give new ideas to others.